# Hadoop: maximum-am-resource-percent is insufficient to start a single application

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop and Hive.

I'm using Hadoop 2.6.4 (binary I got from internet) & Hive 2.0.1 (binary I got from internet).
I can create a database and table in hive.

However when I try to insert a record into a previously created table I get:
"org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: maximum-am-resource-percent is insufficient to start a single application in queue"

I'm using default so there is one queue "root" and it is running

## yarn-site.xml

```
 <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler</value>
</property>
```

## capacity-scheduler.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
    <value>1.0</value>
    <description>
      Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run
      application masters i.e. controls number of concurrent running
      applications.
    </description>
  </property>
```

According to the documentation this means I have allocated 100% to my one and only default scheduler queue.
[https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html]
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent / yarn.scheduler.capacity..maximum-am-resource-percent
Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run application masters - controls number of concurrent active applications. 
Limits on each queue are directly proportional to their queue capacities and user limits.
 Specified as a float - ie 0.5 = 50%. Default is 10%. This can be set for all queues with yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent and can also be overridden on a per queue basis by setting
 yarn.scheduler.capacity..maximum-am-resource-percent"

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try increasinn the parameter yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=0.1
to a higher value.

Answer (score 0):

Please also make sure that all your nodes are running.

For that you can go on the default page: SERVER_URL:8088/cluster/nodes

I got this message when my unique node has been removed. As a consequence, the total number of memory was 0mb.